# fiber of a branched covering of curves over a branch point

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, though possibly geometrically disconnected. Let $f : X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite map of smooth curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $P\in\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ be a branch point, then the fiber $X_P$ is the Spec of a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. Is there a classification of such algebras? Must they all be of the form:

$$\prod_i L_i[x]/(x^{e_i})$$
for various finite extensions $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$?

My underlying question is - The absolute Galois group $G_\mathbb{Q}$ acts on the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ points of $X$ lying above $P$. Suppose $Q$ is a point of $X$ lying above $P$ with ramification index $e$. Then must $Q^\sigma$ also have ramification index $e$ for any $\sigma\in G_\mathbb{Q}$?

What is the right language to say things like this? I want to say that $G_\mathbb{Q}$ acts on the fiber $X_P := X\times_{f,Y,P}\text{Spec }\mathbb{Q}$, but that fiber is not the Spec of an etale $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and so you can't just say that $\pi_1(P) = \pi_1(\text{Spec }\mathbb{Q}) = G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ acts on its geometric fiber. On the other hand, $G_\mathbb{Q}$ certainly does act on the points of $f^{-1}(P)$.

EDIT: Okay, one way to argue the stuff about ramification index is that since $P$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, the pullback of the divisor $(P)$ has the form $\sum_{Q\in f^{-1}(P)}e_Q(f)(Q)$, and is fixed by $G_\mathbb{Q}$, which implies that points $Q\in f^{-1}(P)$ must get sent to points with the same ramification index. Is it possible to translate this argument into stuff about finite (possibly ramified) $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras?

Comment: Isn't every nonconstant map between curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ both finite and generically etale?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hmm, now that I think about it, yes (if the curves are smooth). I just wrote that to be safe. Deleting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a local question, so let's restrict our attention to the affine case. This looks like a map $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x, y]/f(x, y)$ for some polynomial $f$. The fiber at a $\mathbb{Q}$-point $x = a$ is

$$\mathbb{Q}[y]/f(a, y) \cong \prod \mathbb{Q}[y]/f_i(y)^{m_i}$$

where $f_i(y)$ are the irreducible factors of $f(a, y)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ (by CRT). This is similar to but somewhat more complicated than your suggestion: we do get various finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ but, for example, $\mathbb{Q}[y]/(y^2 + 1)^2$ is not covered by your suggestion.

The absolute Galois group acts on the base change of this fiber to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. I think that gets you what you want?

Comment: Must the restriction of any such $f$ to the preimage of the affine line look like that? There are definitely smooth curves which don't have a smooth planar model. I mean your argument will definitely work if you restrict to the localization of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ at $(x-a)$, though it's interesting that the argument in this case seems to depend on the primitive element theorem here applied to extensions of the function field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ (without which I don't think you can apply CRT)...

Comment: @oxeimon: sorry, yes, I had in mind that we should perform as much localization as necessary.